# Is there a way for the user to select the drive letter for file handling in C?

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm writing a program that will use a flash drive for storing user's biometrics. However, flash drive's 'letters' are not the same, which is why if I used the file handling, it may not store on their flashdrives. I'm trying to make a prompt that will ask the user their drive letter before proceeding to register their data.

Here's some codes that I wrote but it seems like it's not working...

```c
int main() {
    char name = "tester";
    int numshit = 5;

    char drivelet;
    
    printf("Enter drive letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &drivelet);

    FILE *fp;
    char temp = toupper(drivelet);
    char path[] = "?:\\uvuvuuv.txt";
    path[0] = temp;
    fp = fopen(path, "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", name, numshit);
    fclose(fp);

    system("cls");

    FILE *bio;
    temp = toupper(drivelet);
    char path1[] = "?:\\uvuvuuv.txt";
    path1[0] = temp;
    bio = fopen(path1, "r+");

    while (bio == NULL) {
        printf("No card detected. Please insert card.");
        system("cls");
        bio = fopen(path1, "r+");
    }
    printf("Card detected!");
    fclose(bio);
}
```

This is just a draft I did on a separate file.

I want it to check if it will redirect to the drive I inserted with the letter I inputted at the first prompt, that's why I made it `w+` so that I can check if it really works (by checking if it created the file inside the drive)

I also put some lines here that will check if the card was detected using the drive letter the user inputted but the program stops after I input the drive letter.

Comment: `fp = fopen(path, "w+");` Always check after `fopen` if `fp == NULL`.

Comment: ***the program stops after i input the drive letter*** does it crash? Do you see a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Have you tried using a *debugger* to either catch any possible crash, or to step through the code statement by statement to see what really happens?

Comment: On an unrelated note, most Windows filesystems are set up as case-insensitive. You don't need that `toupper(drivelet)`

Comment: `char name = "tester"; `